# Thinkaurelius Titan configuring BerkeleyDB

Tags: configure, berkeley-db, graph-databases, titan

I am trying to created a Thinkaurelius titan datastore using:

```
TitanGraph graph = TitanFactory.open("/tmp/graph")
```

The documentation can be found at https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/wiki/Using-BerkeleyDB
But each time I open the graph a new datastore is being created. I even tryed using the configure object but it did not help. Has any one worked on this before? I wanto create a titan datastore that should be reusable, i.e. it should not create a new datastore each time I open it.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Try using a path outside `/tmp` as it is usually wiped after each reboot. For example: `/home/<user>/.titan`.

Comment: Yes, I tried that already and it did not help, I am getting the vertices from the opened titangraph and checking the number of vertices in the iterator and it is always 0

Comment: i assume that you are also doing stopTransaction(SUCCESS) or after mutating the graph.  If you change the graph and don't commit the transaction it won't persist the change for the next time you open it.

Comment: I have tried bith tx.commit(); and graphDB.stopTransaction(Conclusion.SUCCESS); but I still have the same problem!

Comment: I am able to add vertices, relationships, get the vertices, update them etc after opening the graph which means the transactions are persisted. But when I call the titanFactory.open() again, instead of opening the already existing graph, it creates an empty graph.

Comment: any suggestion please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the changes aren't being committed to the database. Look more into how transactions work.

https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/wiki/Transaction-Handling